# Error of approximation of an integral $\int_0^3 e^{-\sin x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, approximation

Let:
$$
I=\int_0^3 e^{-\sin x}dx
$$
$I$ has been approximated using rectangle midpoint formula $S$ (so $S(f)=H\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k+x_{k-1}}{2}$), dividing interval $<0;3>$ to $150$ equal subintervals.

Prove that:

a) $|I-S|<10^{-4}$

b) $I>S$

so for part a), I used a formula that calculates rectangle midpoint formula error:
$$
|I-S|=E(f)=\frac{1}{24}H^2(b-a)f''(\mu)
$$
Where $H$ is the length of subintervals and $\mu\in(a,b)$

From there I got that
$$
|I-S|<10^{-4}\frac{1}{2}f''(\mu)
$$
so I just needed to prove that
$$
f''(\mu)=e^{-\sin \mu}(-\sin^2 \mu+\sin \mu +1)<2
$$
here I subsidized $t=\sin \mu$, where $t\in <0;1>$

I got that $g(0),g(1)<2$ (where $g$ is the subsidized function $f''$)

Since $g'(t)=e^{-t}t(t-3)$, function $g$ has extremal values only is $0$ and $3$, which I already checked, as borders of the interval.

For the part b), unfortunately I have no ideas (except maybe calculating the integral analitically, and then writing a program that would calculate it's approximation, but I don't think that's the best solution)

Please verify my method for part a), and **give me some tips on solving part b)**

Comment: @LutzLehmann why? If you look at sine diagram, it gets negative before $0$ and after $\pi$ and they are both out of the domain. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You are right, I retract most of my comment, except the point where you say that 3 is an interval border for $t$. // You should also be more careful when using absolute values, make sure that then both sides of the equation are always positive.

Comment: @LutzLehmann ah, so I should use limes for calculating g(0) and g(1) here? Is that what you meant?

Comment: This is bordering on nitpicking, but: The conclusion from the form of $g'$ should be that $g$ is monotonic on $t\in[0,3]$, so that the values at $t=0,1$ are indeed the extremal values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error formula holds without the absolute value... You have that
$$
I-S = \frac{1}{24}H^2 (b-a) f''(\mu)
$$

If you show that $f''(\mu)>0$, you have your proof.